# Why is SQL Server Compact Edition missing from the list of server types in SQL Server Management Studio 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce, ssms

I have both 'SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 1' and 'SQL Server Management Studio 2008' (SSMS) installed on my PC. In the past, I was able to select 'SQL Server Compact Edition' from the list of 'Server Types' in the 'Connect to Server' dialog within SSMS. This entry is now missing and I have not been able to restore it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are apparently two ways that this can happen.

1. 'SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP1 Query Tools' has been uninstalled.
2. The 'Repair' option was selected during the installation of 'SQL Server 2008'. Check [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955965) under the section titled 'SQL Server Management Studio 2008 Integration' for details.

The solution to both causes is to reinstall 'SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP1 Query Tools'. The installation package is named 'SSCESqlWbTools' and can be found on either the 'SQL Server 2008' installation media or on the [Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=DC614AEE-7E1C-4881-9C32-3A6CE53384D9).